# R.String missing for Android Studio Library Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I created a library project following these steps:

1. Create a normal Android Project without an Activity
2. Change `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` to `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` from *build.gradle*
3. Delete the line `applicationId "..."` from *build.gradle*

Then I included the library project in my application:

1. Updated my *settings.gradle* to `include ':app', '..:NotifierLib:library'`
2. Added library module in `File -> Project Structure ... -> app -> Dependencies -> Add -> Module dependency`

Everything works fine, I can build the app and run it on my device, but it crashes when a component specified within the library tries to access a library resource. In my case I have  implemented a BroadcastReceiver and a PreferenceItem. If the BroadcastReceiver is called, it updates the item and therefore accesses some string resources:

```
String key = context.getResources().getString(R.string.myKey);
```

However, when the BroadcastReceiver gets called, the app crashes with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: goe.math.uni.notifierlib.R$string
```

As you see the app tries to access `R.string` within the library, which fails, although the resources exist within the library. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using minifyEnabled true on the build?

Comment: No I am using minifyEnabled false.

Comment: Have you done step by step debugging and break at where it's supposed to read the string?  And without seeing more code it is going to be hard to determine the issue

Comment: I first developed all in one project and everything worked fine. The error occurred after I split up the project in an application and a library project by following the above steps and moving the regarding code from one project to the other. So the error shouldn't be in the code itself. Should it?

Comment: The resources could be the problem then. Put a copy of the resources in the main app and see what happens

Comment: Thanks, that pushed me in the right direction. I didn't remove the declarations from the application project. So the same string resources were available in the application and library project. Removing them from the application project fixed that issue. However, how can I avoid such conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,  answer then.  The resources were causing a conflict. 
There is really no one way to avoid conflicts. But,  when I've done projects where I have a library I've created,  the best way I've found to avoid conflicts is to create my library from the very start. Trying to pull stuff out to make a library from existing code can be troublesome.

Comment: Thanks. If there is no possibility to handle conflicts, is there any possibility to override resources of the library if present in the application module?

Comment: Android Studio is supposed to automatically override the resources from the library when they are local in the main app. It's doesn't seem to work every time though.